# Restoring a hidden application in Application Finder

Tags: xfce

Application Finder (`xfce4-appfinder`) has a feature where I can right click on an application and Hide it. I have done that to an application that appeared double before but now there are no results at all. How can I see which applications are hidden and make these visible again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Xubuntu 18.04.1, I see the instructions to unhide:

[image: Instructions to unhide]

To identify hidden applications, use `grep:`

```
dkb@dkb-xubu:~/.local/share/applications$ grep -i hidden *.desktop
blueman-adapters.desktop:Hidden=true
blueman-manager.desktop:Hidden=true
gigolo.desktop:Hidden=true
gpick.desktop:Hidden=true
libreoffice-math.desktop:Hidden=true
software-properties-drivers.desktop:Hidden=true
dkb@dkb-xubu:~/.local/share/applications$
```

And then delete the corresponding files.

Comment: I had to restart `xfce4-appfinder` by killing the forever running process in order to make that work. Didn't think to do that before.